# elasticsearch - decay documents using property value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

My documents are made of categories. There are 40 different categories these are added to the document manually in database and indexed. This is how my document looks like:

```
{
  "name": "..",
  "categoryA": "..",
  "categoryB": "..",..
  "categoryDecayScore": 0.0 - 1.0
}
```

The documents are considered well covered if they are part of all 40 categories. So to push documents in all categories to the top I wanted to use the decay function to reduce the score of those who are part of less categories.

For this I use the `categoryDecayScore` property which is set at index time. If document is part of all 40 categories than it's `categoryDecayScore` will be `0.0` if it's missing half but has more than a 1/3 it will get a score of `0.2` and if it has less than 1/3 it will get a score of `0.3`.

Then I also increase `categoryDecayScore` by 0.02 for less relavant scores.

**What I want to do:**
I would like documents who have `categoryDecayScore > 0.0` to have their score decayed the farther they are from `0.0`.

This is my filter function:

```
"filter": {
        "exp": {
          "categoryDecayScore" : {
            "origin" : 0.0,
            "scale" : 1.0,
            "offset" : 0.0,
            "decay" : 0.5
          }
        }
}
```

The way I understand documentation here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Is that `origin` is my point of reference and all documents who have `categoryDecayScore > 0.0` will be decayed and any with `categoryDecayScore >= 1.0` will be decayed by `0.5`.

However looking at my results it seems this does not take affect. The top 4 documents all have the same score but here are the `categoryDecayScore` values:

```
{
  _score: 51.970146,
  categoryDecayScore: 0.04
},
{
  _score: 51.970146,
  categoryDecayScore: 0.2
},
{
  _score: 51.970146,
  categoryDecayScore: 0.02
},
{
  _score: 51.970146,
  categoryDecayScore: 0.3
}
```

Is this normal behaviour or am I understanding the decay function incorrectly. My assumption based on docs is:

- origin: point of reference from which distance is calculated
- scale: upper point after which all documents are decayed by value of decay param
- offset: point after which documents are decayed
- decay: decay amount for all documents scored above or at scale value

Note 1:

Using explain flag I noticed with those exp settings the evaluated decay score is always 1. So the 51.. score is just the text matching score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My query is/was correct. The issue was that my range 0.0 - 1.0 was to small. So I decided on using whole integers instead of decimals and range from 0 to 1000. For the exclusion I ten set the origin to 100 instead of 0. This returned the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the decay function parameters is correct. However, in your post you put the decay function (`exp`) clause inside the `filter` clause, which is wrong -- filters are only used to remove documents from the recall set, but cannot affect their score.

To use a decay function, you need to include it inside a `function_score` query. 
In your case you need something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "exp": {
        "categoryDecayScore": {
          "origin" : 0.0,
          "scale" : 1.0,
          "offset" : 0.0,
          "decay" : 0.5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you only want this decay to affect documents having a categoryDecayScore > 0, you can add a filter to the decay function:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "exp": {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "categoryDecayScore": { 
              "gt": 0.0 
            }
          }
        },
        "categoryDecayScore": {
          "origin" : 0.0,
          "scale" : 1.0,
          "offset" : 0.0,
          "decay" : 0.5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that `offset` is 0 by default and `decay` is 0.5 by default, so you don't have to explicitly include those parameters.

The documentation for [Decay Functions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay) under the Function Score Query section has examples of the correct syntax and explanations about the defaults.

Comment: I use the filter under `functions` please see my second edit. Does this still apply ?

Comment: Tried your approach but it's still the same result.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my origin, scale settings. If I increase origin I see exp take effect. Maybe my scale from 0.0 to 1.0 is to small.